# CodeBlocks not showing Turkish characters

Tags: c, character-encoding, codeblocks

I have changed my IDE DevC++ to CodeBlocks. My project include Turkish characters. When using DevC ++, Turkish characters were display. But I changed my IDE DevC++ to CodeBlocks, Turkish character not showing them. CodeBlocks show error message "ENCODING CHANGED. The saved document contained characters which were illegal in the selected encoding. The file's encoding has been changed to UTF-8 to prevent you from losing data."

Please help me. Thanks :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>

void duzenDegistir(char *dizi, int boy){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i,a;
    char *temp;

    for(i=0;i<boy;i++){
        a=rand()%boy;
        *temp=dizi[i];
        dizi[i]=dizi[a];
        dizi[a]=*temp;
    }

    dizi[i+1]='\0';
}



int main(){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    srand((unsigned int)(time(NULL)));
    int k_sayi,i,lang;
    char kucuk_harf[26]="abcdefghijklmnoprstuvwxyz";
    char buyuk_harf[26]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ";
    char sayilar[11]="1234567890";
    char ozel_karakter[13]="!'^+%&/=?_*";
    char *pass, *p;
    char kontrol_buyuk, kontrol_sayi, kontrol_okarakter, secim, duzen;

    printf("Please select the language: (en: 1 /tr: 2): ");
    scanf("%d",&lang);


    if(lang==1){

        do{


    printf("How many characters can the password ?: ");
    scanf("%d",&k_sayi);

    printf("Upper-case letter? (y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c",&kontrol_buyuk);

    printf("Numbers? (y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c",&kontrol_sayi);

    printf("Special characthers?: ");
    scanf(" %c", &kontrol_okarakter);

    pass=(char *)malloc(k_sayi*sizeof(char));

    if(kontrol_buyuk=='y'&&kontrol_sayi=='y'&&kontrol_okarakter=='y'){

        for(i=0;i<k_sayi;i++){
        pass[i]=kucuk_harf[rand()%(sizeof kucuk_harf-1)];
        if(i>1){
            while(i%2==1){
                pass[i]=buyuk_harf[rand()%(sizeof buyuk_harf-1)];
                break;
            }

            while(i%3==2){
                pass[i]=sayilar[rand()%(sizeof sayilar-1)];
                break;
            }

            while(i%(k_sayi-2)==2){
                pass[i]=ozel_karakter[rand()%(sizeof ozel_karakter-1)];
                break;
            }

        }

    }
    }

    if(kontrol_buyuk=='n'&&kontrol_sayi=='y'){

        for(i=0;i<k_sayi;i++){
        pass[i]=kucuk_harf[rand()%(sizeof kucuk_harf-1)];
        if(i>1){

            while(i%3==2){
                pass[i]=sayilar[rand()%(sizeof sayilar-1)];
                break;
            }

        }

    }
    }

    if(kontrol_buyuk=='y'&&kontrol_sayi=='n'){

        for(i=0;i<k_sayi;i++){
        pass[i]=kucuk_harf[rand()%(sizeof kucuk_harf-1)];
        if(i>1){
            while(i%2==1){
                pass[i]=buyuk_harf[rand()%(sizeof buyuk_harf-1)];
                break;
            }

        }

    }
    }

    if(kontrol_buyuk=='n'&&kontrol_sayi=='n'){
        printf("This option will generate a low-security password. You should not forget the upper-case letters and numbers in your passwords ...\n");
        for(i=0;i<k_sayi;i++){
        pass[i]=kucuk_harf[rand()%(sizeof kucuk_harf-1)];

    }
    }




    pass[i]='\0'; // Son indisteki içeriği NULL'a eşitledim ki dizginin sonunu belirtelim.
    printf("\n\n==> Your Password: %s\n\n",pass);
    printf("Would you like to change the password layout? (y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c",&duzen);
    if(duzen=='y'){
        while(duzen=='y'){
            duzenDegistir(pass, k_sayi);
            printf("%s\n",pass);
            printf("Would you like to change the password layout again? (y/n): ");
            scanf(" %c",&duzen);
        }


    }


    free(pass);
    printf("\nWould you like to create the new password? (y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c",&secim);

    if(secim=='n'){
        printf("\n\nRemember to keep your passwords and change them frequently. See you again...\n\n");
    }


    }while(secim=='y');

    }



    if(lang==2){

        do{


    printf("Parola kaç karakterli olsun?: ");
    scanf("%d",&k_sayi);

    printf("Büyük harf olsun mu? (y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c",&kontrol_buyuk);

    printf("Sayı olsun mu? (y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c",&kontrol_sayi);

    printf("Özel karakter olsun mu?: ");
    scanf(" %c", &kontrol_okarakter);

    pass=(char *)malloc(k_sayi*sizeof(char));

    if(kontrol_buyuk=='y'&&kontrol_sayi=='y'&&kontrol_okarakter=='y'){

        for(i=0;i<k_sayi;i++){
        pass[i]=kucuk_harf[rand()%(sizeof kucuk_harf-1)];
        if(i>1){
            while(i%2==1){
                pass[i]=buyuk_harf[rand()%(sizeof buyuk_harf-1)];
                break;
            }

            while(i%3==2){
                pass[i]=sayilar[rand()%(sizeof sayilar-1)];
                break;
            }

            while(i%(k_sayi-2)==2){
                pass[i]=ozel_karakter[rand()%(sizeof ozel_karakter-1)];
                break;
            }

        }

    }
    }

    if(kontrol_buyuk=='n'&&kontrol_sayi=='y'){

        for(i=0;i<k_sayi;i++){
        pass[i]=kucuk_harf[rand()%(sizeof kucuk_harf-1)];
        if(i>1){

            while(i%3==2){
                pass[i]=sayilar[rand()%(sizeof sayilar-1)];
                break;
            }

        }

    }
    }

    if(kontrol_buyuk=='y'&&kontrol_sayi=='n'){

        for(i=0;i<k_sayi;i++){
        pass[i]=kucuk_harf[rand()%(sizeof kucuk_harf-1)];
        if(i>1){
            while(i%2==1){
                pass[i]=buyuk_harf[rand()%(sizeof buyuk_harf-1)];
                break;
            }

        }

    }
    }

    if(kontrol_buyuk=='n'&&kontrol_sayi=='n'){
        printf("Bu seçenek düşük güvenlikli parola oluşturacaktır. Parolalarınızda büyük harf ve sayıyı ihmal etmemelisiniz...\n");
        for(i=0;i<k_sayi;i++){
        pass[i]=kucuk_harf[rand()%(sizeof kucuk_harf-1)];

    }
    }




    pass[i]='\0'; // Son indisteki içeriği NULL'a eşitledim ki dizginin sonunu belirtelim.
    printf("\n\n==> Parolanız: %s\n\n",pass);
    printf("Parola düzenini değiştirmek ister misiniz? (y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c",&duzen);
    if(duzen=='y'){
        while(duzen=='y'){
            duzenDegistir(pass, k_sayi);
            printf("%s\n",pass);
            printf("Parola düzenini tekrar değiştirmek istermisiniz? (y/n): ");
            scanf(" %c",&duzen);
        }


    }


    free(pass);
    printf("\nYeni parola oluşturmak ister misiniz? (y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c",&secim);

    if(secim=='n'){
        printf("\n\nParolalarınızı saklamayı ve sık sık değiştirmeyi unutmayınız...\n\n");
    }


    }while(secim=='y');

    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check with another editor what encoding your unmodified source file uses. Then change this to UTF-8, at best this editor can do this. After that I would expect that CodeBlocks will not moan and instead show all characters.

Answer (score 0):

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");

Denermisin ?